# Video Conversion to WMV

Tags: c#, video, wmv

A project I am currently working on at work requires the ability to convert videos from other formats to the WMV format. We need to be able to convert virtually any video format that is commonly used to a WMV format. I am looking for a solution allot like On2's flix engine converts other video types to `.flv` videos. I am aware of the encoder that windows offers, but it has a very limited list of video types that it can convert from. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or opinions, or recommendation of software I can use to do this. I need to be able to do the conversions in batch and I need to be able to do them programmatically with C#.

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)?

It seems to be at the core of many open source video conversion utilities, so I imagine you could use it in the scenario you describe.

Comment: I have considered this, but I am not sure if it will have good enough quality

Comment: That's pretty much a config setting

Answer (score 2):

[SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html), the name is really covering the load!

Comment: I need something that I can control within a c# program I am writing though

Comment: imo you can indeed : super is a gui for several commandline tools (including the beforementioned ffmpeg)  I think that all you can do in super, you can do with commandline commands

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you have to be able to decode the file format. You need to set this up with directshow, which is very hard to work with. You can take a look at the mediaportal project for a directshow file player written in C#. Instead of using the video renderer at the end of the directshow graph, you would reencode the video and audio and mux them into a .wmv file. This is a very involved project to get right. You essentially have to mimic a player's ability to play any format and handle failure.

Answer (score 0):

I've been very satisfied using [Quick Media Converter](http://www.cocoonsoftware.com/#us).